# Remove duplicates from an array, then remove nulls, then restructure

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (sizeofarray = 5)

```
$city[0] = 'Newyork'
$city[1] = 'Paris'
$city[2] = 'Paris'
$city[3] = 'Newyork'
$city[4] = 'Amsterdam'
(sizeofarray = 5)
```

I used array_unique() to remove dupes and got this:

```
$city[0] = 'Newyork'
$city[1] = 'Paris'
$city[4] = 'Amsterdam'
(sizeofarray = 3)
```

But now I want this:

```
$city[0] = 'Newyork'
$city[1] = 'Paris'
$city[2] = 'Amsterdam'
(sizeofarray = 3)
```

Is there some function to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be getting empty for 2 and 3. `array_unique` completely removes the duplicate items from the array, so you should be getting the result you're showing in the last snippet. See: http://pastie.org/5114229

Comment: Ok I am sorry.. I am running a loop where $city[2] shows error. Reframing my question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) after you run the array through `array_unique`:

```
$city = array_filter($city);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/array_filter):

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to `FALSE` (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

You may run into an error, however, if one of your array elements is equal to [`"0"`, as when converted to boolean, its value is `false`](http://php.net/manual/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).  In that case, you'll have to use a custom callback function.

---

In your question, it appears that only the array indexing is out of order, and there are not actual empty string elements in your array.  Try running the array though [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) after `array_unique` to reset the indexing:

```
$city = array_unique($city); 
$city = array_values($city);
```

Comment: I am reframing my question. I am running a loop afterwards where $city[2] shows null. It obviously will, because the key itself is absent.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tim Cooper's reply, use `array_values()` to reindex the array:

```
$city = array_unique($city);
$city = array_filter($city);
$city = array_values($city);
```

And make sure same cities have same names, because `'New York' != 'Newyork'`. Otherwise you'll need additional filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$city=array_values(array_unique($city));
```